# Playing video in UITableViewCell iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, tableview

I want to display and play video in a table view cell. my code for that is:
In cellForRowAtIndexPath:

```
 NSURL *videoURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",path,[[arrAboutUs objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"content"]]];
   MPMoviePlayerController* moviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:videoURL];
    [moviePlayer setControlStyle:MPMovieControlStyleNone];
    moviePlayer.scalingMode = MPMovieScalingModeAspectFit;
    [moviePlayer.view setFrame:cell.frame];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:moviePlayer.view];
    moviePlayer.view.hidden = NO;
    [moviePlayer prepareToPlay];
    [moviePlayer play];
```

But it is showing blank. and my video is in MP4 formate.

Comment: Look at this example https://github.com/Gagan5278/TableCellStreaming

it is old but should work with you.

Comment: it is taking so much time to play and display..

Comment: is there anything wrong in my code.

Comment: any reason why you are not using `AVPlayerViewController` instead of deprecated `MPMoviePlayerController`?

Comment: @milan Because I am new for it  I just searched for it and i found number of examples with MPMoviePlayer.  if you have any link or idea for  AVPlayerViewController  pls let me know.

Comment: No..code is perfect. Just try it. Video files are loading from the server. You can add your local files.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you @milan for your valuable suggestion. I use AVPlayerViewController and it working fine. code for that:

```
    AVPlayer*player = [[AVPlayer alloc] initWithURL:videoURL];

        AVPlayerViewController* playerController = [[AVPlayerViewController alloc] init];


        playerController.player = player;
       [self addChildViewController:playerController];

        [cell.contentView addSubview: playerController.view];
        playerController.view.frame = cell.frame;

        [player play];
```