# Understanding visual format constraints in iOS Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, nslayoutconstraint

I know about setting constraint in  **InterfaceBuilder**  *ex. Leading, trailing, top, bottom, fixed width etc..*
I found some constraint code, I don't know what this code trying to set which constraint, What is exactly meaning of below visual format constraints?

```
  NSDictionary *binding = @{@"v" : self.view};
    NSDictionary *metrics = @{@"height" : @(self.height)};
    [self.contentView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[v]|" options:0 metrics:nil views:binding]];
    [self.contentView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:[v(==height)]|" options:0 metrics:metrics views:binding]];
```

Comment: look here https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/VisualFormatLanguage.html

Comment: on that doc `cmd +f`  "v". no results.   can you tell me What is "v" & "height" ?

Comment: v is your view binded in the dictionary while V uppercased is vertical, as well as H is horizontal

Comment: Following website will help you.

https://autolayoutconstraints.com

Comment: Dont stick with VFL anymore VFL cant account for safe area layout guides it can only account top layout guides. You can write perfect VFL to screw up your UI in iPhoneX

Comment: There are a lot of compelling arguments to avoid using VFL at this stage of iOS development. Won't work with safe area layout guides as @SandeepBhandari mentions. Also extremely prone to developer error. If you're looking to understand existing constraints, I'd look to translate them to anchor-based. If you want to make new constraints, I'd suggest anchor-based instead.

Comment: @SandeepBhandari can you look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47076230/play-video-in-active-uitableviews-cells) ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> H:|[v]|

`H` represents that the constraints are meant to be added horizontally, similarly `V` is for vertical.

`|` represents super view as indicated by the binding dictionary. `NSDictionary *binding`

`[v]` represents the view itself.

So `H:|[v]|` resolves to leading & trailing constraints with `0` constant.

> V:[v(==height)]|

Similarly here, view is given a bottom constraint and a height constraint with a constant `height` as mentioned in `NSDictionary *metrics`.

Please refer https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/VisualFormatLanguage.html for more information.

Comment: For `H` left `|` refers to leading, and similarly for `V` the left `|` refers to top, and the right `|` refers to bottom.

Comment: Got it, Great explanation!

Comment: can you please [answer this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47076230/play-video-in-active-uitableviews-cells) also?

Answer (score 0):

As GoodSp33d suggested to me.

Your constraint is-

(1) **leading** & **trailing** to **self.view** is **0**
I have converted above constraint into diffrent way

(2) **ContentView's bottom** assigned to **self.view**

(3)**Constant height constraint**

Constraint in another form as-

```
    [self.contentView.leadingAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.view.leadingAnchor].active = YES;
    [self.contentView.trailingAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.view.trailingAnchor].active = YES;
    [self.contentView.bottomAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.view.bottomAnchor].active = YES;


    NSLayoutConstraint *heightConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.view
                                                                        attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight
                                                                        relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                                           toItem:nil
                                                                        attribute:NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute
                                                                       multiplier:1.0
                                                                         constant:self.height];
    [self.view addConstraint:heightConstraint];
```